# Leaflet scaling on mobile

Tags: leaflet, mobile

I'm using leaflet with OSM for two different web mapping projects and have the same problem with both. On both, I set bounds and zoom limits and create the map, and they work nicely on my laptop (Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on Windows 8.1). However, there are problems on mobile: the scaling appears to be wrong, as if it were zoomed to 150%, so that text in the map and images both in the map and elsewhere are blurry, and leaflet controls positioned in bottom-right or bottom-left appear slightly off the edge of the screen. However, this doesn't change if I manually change the scaling in the browser on mobile, and isn't affected by having the line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

in my code or

```
body{zoom:100% !important;}
```

in my css. This happens exactly the same on Chrome on Android on a couple of different phones and on Safari on iOS.

You can see one of the two sites here (still very beta in lots of ways): https://cymraeg.ling.cam.ac.uk/?map=6

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

There is a padding set to `1px` for #mapdiv in your styles.css file. Removing it solves the control problem.

Text is not blurry with Firefox on my phone and laptop.

Comment: thanks very much indeed for this! this solves some other problems I've been having with firefox on windows/mac, but hasn't changed the position of the control in the bottom left (off the bottom of the screen) for me, nor the blurriness. To demonstrate, here is a screenshot from chrome in windows with mobile view from the developer tools: https://i.imgbox.com/5WRZ6mMp.png. and here is a screenshot from chrome on android: https://i.imgbox.com/QVS93hVr.png. you can see that the control is positioned wrongly and the map times are blurry, as if scaled.